# Wordpress Calendar only to show months without days

Tags: jquery, wordpress, events, calendar

We have a WordPress website and we need to have event calendar in footer as widget (all that is fine). The issue is we need to show only months from (1-12) without any dates and days as u can see it in (http://www.derasat.org.bh) in footer, its not working only HTML and style applied

Comment: you can create your own plugin to do this .

Comment: Check Out http://ryanfait.com/resources/wordpress-event-list-calendar-plugin/. It will be useful

Comment: Thanks guys, but still that doesn't meets my requirements. anybody can guide me to my requirement please. thanks Shan for sharing the link, but that is not what i am looking for